# @Nullable and SonarQube 'Conditionally executed blocks should be reachable' warning

Tags: java, sonarqube, nullable, notnull

Package has following package-info.java:

```
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
package foo;
import javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault;
```

Class has the following method:

```
private static String toIsoString(@Nullable Instant dateTime) {
  return dateTime == null ? null : dateTime.toString();
}
```

On which SonarQube (Version 6.2, SonarJava 4.14.0.11784) gives the following warning (squid:S2583):

[image]

How can I convince SonarQube that the code is actually correct?

Interestingly, SonarLint plugin (3.0.0.2041) in Idea doesn't generate the same warning.

Comment: May be check from where this is being called? It might be detecting that you are always passing null into the method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, this problem was caused by us using `sonar-scanner` without specifying `sonar.java.libraries`. Since it's multimodule maven project it wasn't clear to us how to specify `sonar.java.libraries` correctly.

Nicolas Peru, from SonarSource, suggested that we should use sonar maven plugin, instead of `sonar-scanner`, as the plugin has access to build classpath of the project. Indeed that solved this problem for us.

Comment: Adding link to ggroup thread relevant to this conclusion : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/yHH8IQ6Hhcw

Answer (score -2):

The [JavaDoc of `@Nullable`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/javax/annotation/Nullable.html) says (emphasis mine)

> This annotation is useful mostly for overriding a Nonnull annotation. **Static analysis tools should generally treat the annotated items as though they had no annotation**, unless they are configured to minimize false negatives.

Correspondingly, SonarJava ignores the annotation.

If you'd like to challenge the course of action taken in SonarJava, please [open a thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube) :-)

Comment: I would agree that if just 'Nullable' annotation is present it could be ignored, as by default methods could take null arguments in Java. However, in this case the package-level annotation indicates that by default arguments cannot be null and 'Nullable' on particular argument overrides that default. Please look at javadoc for 'javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault', which says: "This annotation can be applied to a package, class or method to indicate that
the method parameters in that element are nonnull by default unless there is...An explicit nullness annotation"

Comment: @maximdim if you'd like to challenge the course of action taken in SonarJava, please [open a thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube)

Comment: Done. Thanks. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/yHH8IQ6Hhcw

Comment: You have quoted the Javadoc for FindBugs's version of `@Nullable`.  FindBugs has a [crazy definition of `@Nullable` that is different from every other tool](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#findbugs-nullable).  FindBugs has no right to specify what other "static analysis tools should" do, so one should disregard the bolded part of your quote.

Comment: Downvoters: I've stated what the rule does. If you'd like to challenge the course of action taken in SonarJava, please [open a thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube) in the SonarQube Google Group.